# How to add hyperlink to a textrange without affecting the styling in c# powerpoint vsto add-in?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, vsto, powerpoint, textstyle

I have several agenda slides in which I want to link each item in the list to a specific slide. I am storing the linked slide information in c# object but can't relate with the textrange c# object. The only way that works is to use hyperlinks which causes items to change into hyperlink stlye. I need to keep the styling where the colors are different for active and passive chapters.

Do you know any way to disalble hyperlink stlye for text defined as hyperlinks or any way to store information and trigger click event for a textrange object?

Comment: Instead of applying the hyperlink to the text itself, apply it to a filled but 99% transparent rectangle drawn on top of the text.

Comment: I also thought that. Our workaround creates the agenda slides automatically by searching slides and shapes sequentially. Thus, any update alters the agenda slides. For that reason I thought that it would be hard to handle the rectangles when slides are updated. Is this a valid concern? As a note: I am just handed this code to fix bugs and functionality, the core coding has been done by somebody else. So, I avoid to change most of the code as much as possible.

Comment: When you create each hyperlinked rectangle, add a .Tag to it so you can identify it later. Then when there are updates, the first thing you do is delete all the hyperlinked rectangles, then create new ones. See Working with Tags (and a bit about Functions)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00815_Working_with_Tags_-and_a_bit_about_Functions-.htm and Using Tags
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00722_Using_Tags.htm